# SystemInfo explanation in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

In vba code I have following line:

```
Public SysInfo As SystemInfo
dim details = SysInfo.UserDetails
```

I have no luck to find that SystemInfo class on google, could you help me to get description of the class?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227579(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: just inside a module. I did not find any type definition for SystemInfo, only initialization like new SystemInfo

Comment: What method was then used on this class? SysInfo.something... What was the something?

Comment: @QHarr SysInfo.UserDetails

Comment: I looked around, and yes you are right!

Answer (score 0):

You will find more information on this by reading Chapter 9 of the VBA Developer's handbook

[VBA and System Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227582(v=vs.60).aspx)

Using the [SystemInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227579(v=vs.60).aspx)

There is little within VBA for getting system info. This primarily done through Windows API calls.